# .htaccess setup to redirect domain's IP to domain.com and remove WWW

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've been looking everyone and I can't seem to find the proper htaccess to do both of these.

I don't want people to be able to visit my site by IP address. 1.1.1.1

Instead, redirect 1.1.1. >> mydomain.com

I don't want people to be able to view www.mydomain.com, instead ridirect to mydomain.com

How can I get both of these?

Thank you!

Comment: remove the default conf to point to your site on your apache config. Or you can check the host with php and redirect accordingly

Comment: I don't have a default conf file on my hosting account? I'm a newbie at this htaccess stuff. How can I do it via HTaccess?

Comment: I finally got it!! I'm using this:   Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Now www goes to mydomain.com and my ip address (i.e. 1.1.1.1) goes to mydomain.com :-) Thank you all!

Comment: Glad you figured it out